# disable escaping characters: jade-loader webpack

Tags: angularjs, pug, webpack, angular-material

In views all goes fine, however when I'm trying to load jade template into Angular Material dialog:

```
  $mdDialog.show({
    template: require('./file.jade'),
    controller: 'Ctrl as vm',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: event,
    locals: { data: vm.data },
   })
```

i have un escaped issue, angular says:

> Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [] in expression
>   [\"user.cancel()\"]

cause it transpiles:

from:

```
div(ng-click="user.cancel()")
```

to:

```
<div ng-click=\"user.cancel()\"></div>
```

> != didn't
>   help

**How to solve it globaly?**

Thanks